# How to send message to specific channel regulary in irssi?

Tags: perl, irc, irssi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need some info on IRC BOTS using PERL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122000/need-some-info-on-irc-bots-using-perl)

How to write script/plugin to irssi which will be send specific text on some channel?? 
Maybe once a week.

Maybe is better way to send message to specific IRC channel in other script language.
 I`s necessary to send message once a week.

I found only this question: [Perl Irssi scripting: How to send msg to a specific channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863746/perl-irssi-scripting-how-to-send-msg-to-a-specific-channel)

And I wrote some code in ruby.
https://gist.github.com/1653215

Comment: The other question got answered.. so where exactly do you have problems? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to just write a very small script in Perl using Bot::BasicBot.
See [Need some info on IRC BOTS using PERL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122000/need-some-info-on-irc-bots-using-perl) for details